# Windows 7 Task Scheduler - not working when in "Run whether user logged in or not" mode

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to use a [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) task. This is working when I have the following settings:

[image]

But, when I change it to the following,

[image]

Then nothing happens. I tried to debug this issue, but I could not find any way to find why this issue happened.